# "To jog in stride with someone, particularly in silence."

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, foreign-phrases

Looking for a single word, or short phrase, in any language, that approximates to that concept: "to jog in stride with someone, particularly in silence."

This - if our collective wisdom can find it - is going to become a tattoo, so it is *that* important.

Apparently I need to include a "sample usage" or it will be considered off-topic. The usage is fairly self-evident from the phrase itself, but for example: "I love the feeling of jogging in stride with someone, particularly in silence." To which someone thoughtfully replies, "Ah yes, in Urdu there is an exact word for that, it's (magical Urdu word goes here)."

Doesn't have to be Urdu of course.

Thanks.

Comment: The community rule for `single-word-requests` tag goes something like - "**To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE DEMONSTRATING HOW THE WORD WOULD BE USED**". Could you provide any sentence/ usage example, albeit with a blank where users can fill in?

Comment: Is your question related to the way soldiers walk together? If so, the phrase would be **to march lock-step** (I've seen the spelling variant  **lockstep** too) or simply **lockstep** as a noun. The German translation would be **Gleichschritt** if that is more to your liking.

Comment: Thanks @dukerasputin - that's barking up the right tree, in that it's a foreign word for something close to the concept. Though in general the concept is more about running, or even spiritual.

Comment: Well also in German you can apply the word more generally, as in **im Gleichschritt laufen** (run in lockstep), even though it won't lose its military connotation.

Comment: I think normally you'd *pace* them if you ran alongside, roughly matching stride.

Comment: @HotLicks That was what I considered initially also, but I think *pacing* is (just a hair) more active than what the OP wants. I think the OP is looking for something more like supportive companionship, someone coming alongside lending mainly moral support - kind of like a [spotter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotting_%28weight_training%29) for someone doing weight training in a gym. The first runner sets the pace; the companion simply runs silently alongside.

Comment: @Lawrence - I believe that runners use "pacing" in a different sense, meaning "keeping pace with", vs "setting the pace for".  (But I'm no runner.)

Comment: [Shhhh ... everyone ... let's tell him something like "my other tattoo is misspelled too" in Spanish, so he gets this done all wrong. :-)]  [j/k ;-)]

Comment: Would this be the act of striding in synchronized fashion while jogging in silence, wearing identical straw hats, and juggling miniature toy giraffes made of pastry dough, pine needles, and old sales receipts? There's a word for that, I'm sure, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: Heh, some nice ideas here. This is going to be one ornate tattoo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"I love the feel of *pack running* with ..."

To me your request brought to mind the idea of how dogs and wolves run long distances together.  Looking into this idea of [persistence hunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_hunting) brought up the term *parforce*, which is related to parcour/parkour; though this latter terms brings in more of a sense of agility/acrobatics over straight running.

Comment: I like parforce as (to me) a new and obscure discovery, though the whole pack-hunting and dispatching-with-dagger is a little more violent than the original phrase intends. Thanks though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **running in concert**.

In this expression, the word concert means both "together" and "in accord or harmony".

*Unfortunately, "Concert" doesn't not always match with silence*.